# Google Maps Geolocation API Add Wifi Access Points

Tags: php, geolocation, wifi

I am using  Google Maps Geolocation API with wifiAccessPoints array to get a location which works well. I would like to find out if I can add new access points with latitude and longitude that are used by the API or modify the latitude and longitude of an existing access point for higher accuracy.